# jQuery Plugin: How do I test the configuration of my plugin with qunit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, qunit

I am trying out qunit while writing a jQuery plugin and I was wondering how I can test the following:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
        var defaults = {
            foo: function(){
                return 'bar';
            }
        };

        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function(){ ... });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

This is a simple version of my qunit test:

```
module('MyPlugin: Configuration');

test('Can overwrite foo', function(){
    var mockFoo = function(){ 
        return 'no bar';
    };

    //equals(notsure.myPlugin({ foo: mockFoo }, 'no bar', 'Overwriting failed');
});
```

So I was wondering how I could expose internal methods/members from my plugin inside my tests?

Comment: Not a lot of response. Did I ask something weird? If I can improve the question I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice after I made my bounty I found a really good site that explains how to use .data() to expose plubic properties and methods.

Here you can find the whole blog post: [building object oriented jquery plugin](http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html).

This is whole example from the above link so all credits go to the author of the blog post.

```
(function($){
   var MyPlugin = function(element, options)
   {
       var elem = $(element);
       var obj = this;
       var settings = $.extend({
           param: 'defaultValue'
       }, options || {});

       // Public method - can be called from client code
       this.publicMethod = function()
       {
           console.log('public method called!');
       };

       // Private method - can only be called from within this object
       var privateMethod = function()
       {
           console.log('private method called!');
       };
   };

   $.fn.myplugin = function(options)
   {
       return this.each(function()
       {
           var element = $(this);

           // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
           if (element.data('myplugin')) return;

           // pass options to plugin constructor
           var myplugin = new MyPlugin(this, options);

           // Store plugin object in this element's data
           element.data('myplugin', myplugin);
       });
   };
})(jQuery);
```