# test jQuery Plugin variable with QUnit

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, qunit

I have already seen this link:
[jQuery Plugin: How do I test the configuration of my plugin with qunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272916/jquery-plugin-how-do-i-test-the-configuration-of-my-plugin-with-qunit)

But I haven't understand if is the same case or not so I ask again.

I have a simple plugin like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({      
        miPlugin: function (argumentOptions) {
            var defaults = {
                txt: 'txt'
            }
            var options = $.extend(defaults, argumentOptions);

            return this.each(function () {
                var o = options;
                var obj = $(this);
                var textSend = '';

                obj.mouseup(function(e) {
                    textSend = 'test';
                });
            });
        }
    });     
})(jQuery);
```

I would like to check the variable textSend is possible when mouseUp trigger?

This is my test with QUnit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var testfield = $('.txt');
  $('.txt').myPlugin({});   

  module('Simple');
    test("Simple", function(){
        testfield.focus();
        testfield.select(); 
        var obj = testfield.trigger( $.Event( "mouseup") );

    });
});
```

How can I test the var textSend on mouseUp event?

Thanks

Comment: One suggestion is store plugin config data on element using `data()`. When stored as object you benefit from prototypical inheritance so in your tests only have to reference object once, then check properties

Comment: can you provide a simple example please? @charlietfl

Comment: `obj.data('miPlugin',{defaults: defaults, otherVars{textSend : textSend })`

Comment: ok but how to get it in tests?

Comment: could you please explain with  a simple example in an answer? @charlietfl

Comment: get it in tests `var pluginData = testfield.data('miPlugin')` then after mouse event `alert(pluginData.otherVars.textSend )`

Comment: ok but in the Plugin how to implement otherVars? @charlietfl

Comment: by creating object instead of individual variables

Comment: it doesn't work, can you please print a simple plugin with that test please? @charlietfl